# Notification `notify()` cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm using a simple code to push notifications in Android through a function. This function is the following :

```
public void sendNotification(View view) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("My notification").setContentText("Hello World!");

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationManager.notify().mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
    }}
```

This is example function i picked on a website.

Everything is ok, the `NotificationCompat.builder` doesn't return any error. But the first `notify()` on the last line return the following error : `Non-static method 'notify()' cannot be referenced from a static context`.

I really don't understand why. The void is placed in my `MainActivity.java`inside my `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {}`

EDIT :

The solution was to remove `NotificationManager.notify().` from `mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
```

Instead of this

```
NotificationManager.notify().mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I tried that already. It works but then my application crash when i try to send a notification using a button. I had another problem with the builder, now it's fixed thanks to your help

Comment: @Ezhno can you share that crash log with question

Comment: I tried to send a notification without any Icon declared. I though this was possible but seems not.

Answer (score 2):

Please see below solution.

```
public void sendNotification(View view) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("My notification").setContentText("Hello World!");

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
}}
```